# EJB with JBoss 7.1.1 leads to WELD 001303 error

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x, sip, jboss-weld

I am trying to fire a get request which leads to a WELD 001303 problem.
    @Path("/test")
    @RequestScoped
    public class TestRest {

```
    @EJB
    HelloWorldInterface helloWorld;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public Response get() {
        return Response.status(201).entity(helloWorld.sayHello()).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response post(String request) {
        String answer = helloWorld.sayHello() + request;
        return Response.status(201).entity(answer).build();
    }

}
```

Using: mss-1.7.0FINAL-jboss-as-7.1.1.FINAL from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobicents/files/Mobicents%20Sip%20Servlets/Mobicents%20Sip%20Servlets%201.7.0.FINAL/

I need this MSS package for sip support.

My project as [Sourecode](https://sipservlets.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1870000000&name=example_project_REST_error.zip&token=Oc_wNVtSOlkDAvPd-jz56l1oCQw:1365610849205) and project as [.war](https://sipservlets.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1870000001&name=my-sipapp.war&token=GYJWAqg94kEr3bbpB1Pr9Tgq694:1365610849205)

Workflow:

```
1. install mss package

2. start mss/jboss server with sip support (standalone-sip.xml) and deploy project

3. open http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-sipapp/rest/test/get
```

--> `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
root cause

org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:598)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:71)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    com.mycompany.app.rest.TestRest$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.get(TestRest$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions. You wait until the weld-core-1.1.8.FINAL.jar will be updated! Or you get the source code and do a hard fix in org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext:

```
public void deactivate() {
if (getBeanStore() != null )
{ getBeanStore().detach(); super.deactivate(); }
}
```

For more information see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1020?_sscc=t